# Why would Inner Join in MySQL return unrelated information?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, where-clause, concatenation

I have two tables on my database, one of it is `order` and the other is `user`.

I want to pull the information for an order along with the associated user that made the order, to do this, I used an `INNER JOIN` to join the two tables on the user's name.

However, the issue is that, it is bringing up the correct order information, but the user is not the related user and is instead the first user record in the database.

Why in the world is this happening?

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT orders.oid, 
           orders.ordernumber, 
           orders.date_requested, 
           orders.date_approved, 
           orders.status, 
           orders.region, 
           orders.users_name, 
           orders.comments, 
           orders.customShippingAddress, 
           orders.approval_comments, 
           orders.approved_by_id, 
           users.firstname, 
           users.lastname, 
           users.address, 
           users.address2, 
           users.city, 
           users.`state`, 
           users.zip, 
           users.phonenum, 
           users.cellnum, 
           users.officenum, 
           users.region, 
           users.shipping_address 
      FROM orders 
INNER JOIN users 
        ON orders.users_name=users.firstname + ' ' + users.lastname
     WHERE orders.oid='$id'";
```

I don't understand why this isn't working.  Can anyone provide me with some direction please?

Comment: You are joining on something that could very well not be unique, you should have something more like inner join... order.user_id = user.id

Comment: If the user makes multiple orders, then wouldn't I have the same problem for uniqueness?

Comment: No, a user can have multiple orders. One user per order though. But what I meant was the fact that if you have 2 users with the same name, they will  both be possible matches for this order. It will simply choose the first match found though.

Comment: `orders.users_name` what happens when you have multiple users with the same name and lastname? :) I would suggestion to save the user_id only in the order and LEFT JOIN on the user_id

Comment: That is why, the order should be linked to a unique user column (the primary key)

Comment: also - you have backticks on the users.state when no other options have them

Comment: I see what you mean.  In this case though, there aren't any duplicates.  There are only ten users.  So, why is it giving me the first name in the database and not a match?  (I will update to user_id, but I want to make sure the accuracy of my statement is correct.)

Comment: I'd need to see some sample data: I can't see why it would return the first user either.

Comment: @Prix all of the names minus the one for testing are random at the moment.  Like adfladsf or 44564789.  None of them are NULL though.  I wonder if the lack of a space and something after that was causing an issue?

Comment: @SherwoodPro well in MySQL `+` is only addition not concatenation like in php and some other languages, which is why there is a explicit `CONCAT`. Nevertheless you should 1) use prepared statement and stop injecting variable directly to your query unless no options(and if no options ensure they are safe to use, using other means) to be safe against SQL Injection and 2) use the user id on your orders rather than something ambiguous like first and last name so if at a later stage you have multiple users that have similar names, that won't produce an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I`m guessing you want

```
ON orders.users_name=CONCAT(users.firstname ,' ',users.lastname)
```

Your version

```
ON orders.users_name=users.firstname + ' ' + users.lastname
```

will probably make some conversions under the hood trying to add things up,+ concats things in sql server,not mysql

Comment: That works great.  If you don't mind me asking, when would I use the + instead of CONCAT if it can mix things up like that?

Comment: @SherwoodPro only in sql server can you use + to concat things,it `s just that mysql is VERY permissive allowing you to add up strings,leading to unpredictable results